# UITabBar disappears after "Back" button

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar, unwind-segue

I have a `UITableView` with a `TabBar` .

When I click a cell it takes me to a new view, and when I click "Back"
I am back to the previous `UITableView`.

Only this time, the `TabBar` doesn't show. How can I make it appear again ?

Notice: The left-most view is the view shown when clicking a cell

[image]

View A and B

[image] 
[image]

After clicking "Back" - UITabBar gone

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your "back" button manually, just set your "back" segue's destination from viewController to navigationController. 
But the correct way to use TabBar and NavController is like this:
[image]

With this setup, it should work.

[image: test]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var array = ["one", "two", "three"]

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

 }
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:   Int) -> Int {

      return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: self)
}

}
```

**EDIT**

Since you hide your tabBar in view B, you need just unhide it.

Add this code to your view B

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
       self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }
```

Comment: That is exactly how I have it set up, with the Tab Bar Controller connected to the Navigation Controller

Comment: Any other suggestions maybe ?

Comment: I made it in my computer and works correctly (check my gif). Without any code or exact picture about your storyboard, segues, etc I can't tell more.

Comment: Thanks for the gif !

In my application, the "Back" button does appear! The problem is that once I click "Back", the UITabBar is gone.... So my flow is:

View A (Tab Bar Present) -> View B ---Back Button---> View A (Tab Bar Gone)

Comment: Ohhh just now I see that you have a UITabBar Too... Let me upload some pictures...

Comment: I just added some pictures of my views

Comment: 1. What's the method when you change tabBar in view B with message? 
2.You segue is push or replace? If replace, did you make a new navbar with back button?

Comment: It's a JSQMessagesViewController... All I do is activate self.tabBarCOntroller?.tabBar.isHidden = true.

My segue is push

Comment: You are a king !

Comment: Just for the next time: give more information about your code, because as you can see, with more detail we can solve it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178948/discussion-between-ofri-and-dris).